# Power Shell copy list code works in master site but not in subsites?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell-3.0

I am using a block of code in power shell to copy my lists from one site to another. It works great on the master level site but will throw all kinds of errors when I try to use it on sub sites. Any ideas?? I am using SharePoint 2013 and Power Shell 3.0.
The site I want to copy from is '$site = New-Object Microsoft.sharePoint.SPSite("http://something.com/")' and the site I want to copy to is '$destinationsite = New-Object Microsoft.sharePoint.SPSite("http://somethingelse.com/")'. This works at this level but when I try this I get errors - '$site = New-Object Microsoft.sharePoint.SPSite("http://something.com/doghouse/cats/")' to '$destinationsite = New-Object Microsoft.sharePoint.SPSite("http://somethingelse.com/cathouse/dogs")'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SPSite object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx) refers to a site collection.

Any subsites within a site collection are represented by [SPWeb objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx), not SPSite objects.

Comment: It was a permissions issue with SharePoint. I created a new list in a sub site and the code worked fine. The lists that I was using was created by another developer so they had their permissions and their permissions and mine seem to be different. Tested your answer though and it worked like a champ!! Thanks!!